# Dataset creation software

Tags: machine-learning, data

Hello I am looking for a dataset for printed english characters but I am not able to find anything concrete. Is there any software which can generate multiple images from one image. I can build my dataset from that.

Comment: What sort of variations on the original image do you want to generate? I doubt there's software that will do exactly what you want, but it would probably be pretty easy to script yourself with something like [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)

Comment: I would like to add variations like background, slant, font, size , as much variation as possible to produce as many images as possible.